# How to get Google Maps destination in external activity?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am wondering if it's possible to query native Google Maps app to get current route destination when the user is being navigated. If so, how to do that?

There are native APIs to request current location from the system, but what I would like to achieve is to get the current route destination coordinate or name. Is there any kind of event broadcasted in the system when user start navigation or an intent that I could capture in my app?

Comment: no you can't open or capture any other app events in your App

Comment: @WaleedAsim I am afraid you are wrong. It is possible in general. I am not sure if it's possible for Google Maps.

Comment: Its not possible for google maps